# How do I get my program in vb.net to move on to the next question after a user answers a multiple choice question?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a multiple choice revision program, but I am having some issues with how I should get my program to generate another question, which I have stored in a database, after the user answers the first generated question? Can someone show me an example of a code or something along those lines please?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class QUI
    'Define all the variables which are meant to be in use'
    Dim ConnectString As String = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=projectdatabase.accdb")
    Dim DataReader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection
    Dim noofq As Integer
    Dim q(noofq) As String
    Dim questionnum As Integer
    'Asks the user to input a number to d
    Private Sub QUI_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Asks the user to input a number to decide how many questions they want to answer'
        noofq = InputBox("Input the number of questions you want. You can choose from 1 to 10.")
        'A counter starting from one to the number of questions the user has inputted'
        For i = 1 To noofq

        Next
        'Open the connection to the database'
        connection.ConnectionString = ConnectString
        connection.Open()
        'Sets the question number to one'
        questionnum = 1
        Label1.Text = "Question " & questionnum & " of " & noofq
        'Retrieves the question and answers from the database'
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3 FROM 1Questions"
        cmd.Connection = connection

        DataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        'Assigns the values from the database to each of the labels and buttons'
        If DataReader.HasRows Then
            DataReader.Read()
            Lblquestion.Text = DataReader.Item("Question")
            RadioButtonA1.Text = DataReader.Item("Answer1")
            RadioButtonA2.Text = DataReader.Item("Answer2")
            RadioButtonA3.Text = DataReader.Item("Answer3")


            DataReader.Close()
        End If
        connection.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
        If RadioButtonA1.Checked And questionnum = 1 Then
            MsgBox("Correct Answer")
        Else
            MsgBox("Incorrect Answer")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

In the question table, if you add a column representing the question code, then you can generate random numbers to choose from the questions. It is also possible to add features such as not repeating the same question.
That is if I understood your question well

Comment: Hi Farag thank you for your suggestion, are you suggesting that I give each question an ID and generate a random question through that. Also after the user answers a question, how would I go to generate another question?

Comment: yes that what i mean, you needs to generate n random number - number of question needed- and save them in list of integer for example, then make loop through this list, and change your Quary to be like `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3 FROM 1Questions where QsId = '"& qlist(i) &"'"` and you can use end sub when user choose a wrong value.

Comment: Okay I understand, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you did not take my advice and turn on Option Strict. Please do so now.

This is what you database table should look like. The `QuestionID` should be an auto-number column and the `CorrectAnswer` column should contain the name of the radio button that will contain the correct answer.

[image]

Your main problem is that you have retrieved all the data from the 1Questions table but you only read the first record. You would have to connect to the database again to retrieve another question. This is a bad idea.

We will retrieve all the data you need and put it in a `DataTable` which is like an in memory table. To start the database objects will be declared and disposed in Using blocks. This is necessary so their `Dispose` methods will be called. You do not declare these objects outside of the method where they are used. You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the `Connection` and pass the `CommandText` and `Connection` directly to the constructor of the `Command`.

I have changed the sql string to include the primary key of the table. I had to guess at the field name so change that to the real name. I also added a field for the correct answer. That may need to be added to the table. The last part of the sql string has an `Order By` clause that will return random questions each time it is run.

The important point here is that the database connection is closed and disposed. All the data we need for the quiz is in the `DataTable`.

I used a `BindingSource` so we can display the data and easily move through the questions.

```
Private ConStr As String = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=projectdatabase.accdb")
Private intNumOfQuestions As Integer
Private questionnum As Integer
Private BndScr As BindingSource

Private Sub QUI_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim strnoofq = InputBox("Input the number of questions you want. You can choose from 1 to 10.")
    If Integer.TryParse(strnoofq, intNumOfQuestions) AndAlso intNumOfQuestions > 0 AndAlso intNumOfQuestions < 11 Then
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand($"SELECT Top {intNumOfQuestions} QuestionID, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, CorrectAnswer 
                                        FROM 1Questions 
                                        ORDER BY Rnd(-Timer()*[QuestionID])", cn)
            cn.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dt.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
        questionnum = 1
        Label1.Text = $"Question {questionnum} of {strnoofq}"
        BndScr = New BindingSource()
        BndScr.DataSource = dt
        Lblquestion.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndScr, "Question")
        Lblquestion.DataBindings.Add("Tag", BndScr, "CorrectAnswer")
        RadioButtonA1.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndScr, "Answer1")
        RadioButtonA2.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndScr, "Answer2")
        RadioButtonA3.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndScr, "Answer3")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid number Of questions.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    If GetSelectedRadioButton(Me).Name = Lblquestion.Tag.ToString Then
        'Correct Answer
    Else
        'Wrong Answer
    End If
    If intNumOfQuestions = questionnum Then
        'End of quiz
    Else
        BndScr.MoveNext()
        questionnum += 1
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetSelectedRadioButton(Container As Control) As RadioButton
    Dim rb = Container.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
    Return rb
End Function
```

It is up to you how to keep score.